# Overflow And Height Disables Smooth Scrolling on Safari

Tags: css, overflow, sticky

I use `position: sticky` and `overflow: hidden` on my project. To prevent the problem of sticky position not working, I used the solution in [this article](https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526): specifying a height to the parent with `overflow`.

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This works well on all desktop browsers and mobile phones, except that on Safari for iOS, the webpage behaves strangely to scrolling. The `overflow-x` value is applied correctly, but smooth scrolling doesn't work.

On normal pages, the page is supposed to scroll more even when I release my fingers. However, on my page, the scrolling stops instantly as I release my fingers.

Is there a way I can stop this behavior, or another way to achieve `overflow` with `sticky`?

Comment: try to add this style also to `html` tag. also try to add `position` to html tag `html{position:relative;overflow-x:hidden}`

Comment: Already tried applying on the html tag, but nothing happens. But I’ll try using relative position.

Comment: @לבנימלכה Just tried `position: relative` but `overflow: hidden` still doesn't work on safari...